# WLST data source testPool- how to set timeout

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, wlst

How to set timeout while testing a datasource using WLST.
When I do the testPool on a dataSource it waits indefinitely.
this also hangs the managed server.
is there a way we can set timeout?

Comment: The default `Statement Timeout` for a datasource is `-1`, which can be indefinite. See what happens if you change this to a value like 30 in your admin console->datasource.

Comment: cant change settings in my production environment at this point.
So trying to check if we can use a timeout in WLST while testing the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the below settings in the `weblogic` connection pools according to your requirement in `weblogic` console.

•Test Frequency—(`TestFrequencySeconds` in the `JDBCConnectionPoolParamsBean`) Use this attribute to specify the number of seconds between tests of unused connections. `WebLogic` Server tests unused connections, and closes and replaces any faulty connections. You must also set the Test Table Name.

•Test Reserved Connections—(`TestConnectionsOnReserve` in the `JDBCConnectionPoolParamsBean`) Enable this option to test each connection before giving to a client. This may add a slight delay to the request, but it guarantees that the connection is healthy. You must also set a Test Table Name